# Anyone knows why my SankeyNetwork is not graphed (apparently there's no error)?

Tags: r, graph, show, sankey-diagram

I wrote the next code and everything works but when I expect the grpah to appear in the viewer screen, it doesn't appear.

```
library(networkD3)

links <- read.csv("C:/Users/tul45082/Desktop/CMA/DNA/linksV2.csv")
nodes <- read.csv("C:/Users/tul45082/Desktop/CMA/DNA/nodesV2.csv")

links$group <- as.factor(c("type_a", "type_b", "type_c", "type_d", 
                            "type_e","type_a", "type_a", "type_a", "type_b", 
                            "type_b","type_b", "type_b", "type_b", "type_c", 
                            "type_c","type_c", "type_c", "type_c", "type_d", 
                            "type_d","type_d", "type_e", "type_e", "type_e"))

nodes$group <- as.factor(c("n1","n2","n2","n2","n2","n2","n3","n3","n3","n3",
                            "n3","n3","n3","n3","n3","n3","n3","n3","n3","n3",
                            "n3","n3","n3","n3","n3"))

my_color <- 'd3.scaleOrdinal() . domain(["type_a","type_b", "type_c","type_d","type_e"])
.range(["#F3EAD1","#C8AE81","#B38C5A","#A38550","#522915"])'


sn <- sankeyNetwork(Links = links, Nodes = nodes, Source = "source",
              Target = "target", Value = "value", NodeID = "names", 
              colourScale = my_color, LinkGroup = "group", 
              NodeGroup="group",fontSize = 10,fontFamily = "Arial", 
              nodeWidth = 0.5,nodePadding = 10, sinksRight = FALSE)
sn
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

looks like your dataframe isn't perfect.

Compare your data with the example data set shown in the `sankeyNetwork` documentation.

```
energy <- jsonlite::fromJSON('https://cdn.rawgit.com/christophergandrud/networkD3/master/JSONdata/energy.json')
str(energy)
```

> ```
> List of 2
>  $ nodes:'data.frame':    48 obs. of  1 variable:
>   ..$ name: chr [1:48] "Agricultural 'waste'" "Bio-conversion" "Liquid" "Losses" ...
>  $ links:'data.frame':    68 obs. of  3 variables:
>   ..$ source: int [1:68] 0 1 1 1 1 6 7 8 10 9 ...
>   ..$ target: int [1:68] 1 2 3 4 5 2 4 9 9 4 ...
>   ..$ value : num [1:68] 124.729 0.597 26.862 280.322 81.144 ...
> ```

Then make your data mimic the example data set as close as possible.

Comment: I am sorry. I don't clearly understand what you mean. Could you ease me more details please?

Comment: `sankeyNetwork` wants data in a pretty particular format. the `energy` example data defines the source node and target node. And stores everything as a list with two data frames, which is confusing, but looks like this list(nodes, links), where links is data.frame(source, target, value). How does your data look? Can you share what it looks like (eg `dput(links)`).